# IF, ELIF, ELSE and OR with Python, not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I´m trying to make this simple project work but is not working at all, i don´t know the if statement with the: 
    if name == " Cher " or name == " Madonna ":
             print ("May I have your autograph please?"), is not working. I tried a lot of combinations and when I digit Jansen as the name it goes to the correct print, and also another name not listed, but when I put Cher or Madonna it goes to the print of the Else statement. Could someone help me to see what is wrong? I´m using the Python IDLE and Python Shell to run it. 
Thanks in advance.

```
password = input("Digit the password: ")

while password != "hello":
   password = input("Digit the password: ")

if password =="hello":
   print ("Welcome to the second half of the program!")
   name = input("What is your name?")

   if name == " Cher " or name == " Madonna ":
         print ("May I have your autograph please?")

   elif name == "Jansen":
         print ("What a Great Name")

   else :
        print (name, "that's a nice name.")
```

Comment: You have spaces inside the string. They are literally treated as spaces. Remove them.

Comment: `"Cher"` is not the same as `" Cher "`.

Answer (score 1):

Tatsuyuki Ishi answered it best (remove leading and tailing white-space from the strings you are trying to compare), however you will generally want to do something like this for input:

```
name.strip()
```

This, by default, strips out white space in front of and at the end of text.

Comment: Hi Tatsuyuki , thanks for the help...but now I´m finding another problem... an error message when I´m trying to run the program that says:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jansen\Desktop\Universidade\Assig4 3.py", line 1, in <module>
    password = input("Digit the password: ");
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined     , do you know how to fix it? Thanks so much again

Comment: Without seeing all the new code, I do have a guess.  The interpreter is thinking hello is a variable and not a string.

Comment: I got you, any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: password = input("Digit the password: ");

while password != "hello":
   password = input("Digit the password: ")

if password =="hello":
   print ("Welcome to the second half of the program!")
   name = input("What is your name?")
   if name == "Jansen":
         print ("What a Great Name")
   elif  name == {"Cher" or "Madonna"}:
         print ("May I have your autograph please?")
   else :
         print (name, "that's a nice name.")

Comment: and here goes the error message:                                                                    Digit the password: hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jansen\Desktop\Universidade\Assig4 3.py", line 1, in 
<module>
    password = input("Digit the password: ");
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I can't say.  Sorry.  If I find time I can try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it goes to the the else statement is because the string of Cher and Madonna has spaces before and after it. It should look like this:

```
password = input("Digit the password: ")

while password != "hello":
    password = input("Digit the password: ")

if password == "hello":
    print("Welcome to the second half of the program!")
    name = input("What is your name?")

    if name == "Cher" or name == "Madonna":
        print("May I have your autograph please?")

    elif name == "Jansen":
        print("What a Great Name")

    else:
        print(name, "that's a nice name.")
```